# C# datetime.tryparse can process error date

Tags: c#, datetime

//error string date

```
string s = "2012-4-5-02";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s,out dt))
    MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
else
    MessageBox.Show("error date");
```

// output : 2012-04-05
// why it can output a good date format? not is display "error date".

Comment: I don't recognize that date format. What do the 4, 5 and 02 mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TryParse` and `Parse` are relatively lenient - more lenient than I personally tend to like.

If you want a more rigorous parsing process, using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

Comment: var formats = new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-M-d", "yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss", };
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
else
        MessageBox.Show("Error date!");

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to fail pass an **explicit** date format to `TryParseExact`, otherwise `DateTime` will take a best guess at what your date might mean, and spit out that.

Comment: You can't specify a format to TryParse - only a format provider, which isn't quite the same thing.